# How to create unkillable activity(Always visible activity) in android?

Tags: android

After installing my application always that application should be opened.(User pressed back button,Home button app should not be closed)

Anyone help me to give some ideas.

Comment: add code you tried

Answer (score 2):

Override in your activity those buttons:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  // nothing to do here    
}
```

You can also check this page here:
[Disable Home, Power, Back Button Android](https://web.archive.org/web/20181008062101/http://www.andreas-schrade.de:80/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/)

or check my Answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33654043/5550768